# How can I manually cancel a .NET core IHostedService background task?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to do some async work after Startup.cs is finished. I've implemented some async tasks in a background service by extending `BackgroundService`.

My question is how to cancel the task from running at a time when I determine? I can only see examples in the documentation for delaying the next cycle.

I've tried to manually execute `StopAsync` but the while loop executes forever (the token is not cancelled, even though I feel like it should be, because I've passed the token to `StopAsync` and the implementation looks like that's what it's meant to do).

Here is some simplified code:

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyBackgroundService> _logger;

    public MyBackgroundService(ILogger<MyBackgroundService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("MyBackgroundService is starting.");

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("MyBackgroundService task doing background work.");

            var success = await DoOperation();
            if (!success)
            {
                // Try again in 5 seconds
                await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
                continue;
            }

            await StopAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't quite catch on to the fact that `ExecuteAsync` is only called once by the framework. So the answer is simply to break out of the loop when you're done.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("MyBackgroundService is starting.");

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("MyBackgroundService task doing background work.");

        var success = await DoOperation();
        if (!success)
        {
            // Try again in 5 seconds
            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }
}
```